# pdflatex hangs on a pending '['

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

The tool `pdflatex` hangs when I leave a '[' pending after the beginning of a TikZ picture.
The same thing happens when I use for instance MikTeX that uses `pdflatex` under the hood. It happens both on Linux and on Windows.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We're using pdflatex for batch processing.
What can we do to avoid it from hanging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the default definition of  `\tikz@signal@path` is a little dangerous (a "quark" in expl3 code terminology) I think it's safe to use a slightly less dangerous `\protected` definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\protected\def\tikz@signal@path{\tikz@signal@path}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which causes tex to show an error rather than loop.

```
! Use of \tikz@@scope@env doesn't match its definition.
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added it to a fixed pre-amble and it works like a charm!

Comment: I'm currently fixing bugs in PGF, but we can't fix this one using e-TeX protection because TikZ still supports DVI mode (for whatever reason).

Comment: @Henri protected is an etex not pdftex feature so available in dvi mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But there are engines which are not e-TeX and use DVI mode.

Comment: Yes but anyone with access to tex has access to etex so not using etex extensions is a very unnecessary constraint these days

Comment: After a recent revision this no longer loops but fail with `! Undefined control sequence.` because an additional assignment has been added in `\path`.