# TeXmaker got stuck?

Tags: errors, texmaker

I have a problem: while compiling a LateX document, the compiler got stuck. I does not return errors or anything, simply it has been executing for over four hours for only 30 pages.

There was not any problem with the same document until today. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall both TeXmaker and MikteX and to update the packages.

I think there is some problem with the packages I use, and there they are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary {er}
\usepackage{tikz-er2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\onehalfspacing

\pagestyle{headings}
%\doublespacing


\begin{document}
```

I am using MikTeX on Windows10.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Valentina

EDIT1
Sorry, I am actually new both to LateX and this community, and I cannot comment back; however I did what @David Carlisle said and in the log file there are about 200 000 rows saying:

```
\tikz@signal@path ->\tikz@signal@path
```

I used tikz package to draw vectors in an example, it is updated, I tried to install and uninstall but nothing different happened. I commented also the package you suggested not to use, but it just continues compiling.

EDIT2:

I am trying to figure out my two accounts, but it seems I own only one both linked to stackExchange and TeX-LateX. However I found this problematic picture:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%x axis
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {-1,1,2,...,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]{\footnotesize $\x$};
%y axis
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \y in {-1,1,2,...,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};

\draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,2); 
\draw[-latex] (0,0)--(3,2.5);
\draw (0.5,1.8) \node{$\bm{v_1}$}; 
\draw (3,2) \node{$\bm{v_2}$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

I can't see anything wrong; I did not have modified it, and before yesterday it worked.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: stop that run and add `\tracingonline=1\tracingmacros=1` , then re-run it and you should see tex logging where it has got stuck (it will still loop so you will still need to kill the process)

Comment: the example isn't much help unless you can edit it to be an example of the problem.

Comment: without an example it is hard to say but if you want comments just on your package list I would use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` not `utf8x` and most likely you do not need `ucs` or `epstopdf` packages, so you could try with those changes.

Comment: You will have an error in one of your tikz pictures.  the log shows [1] [2] as it outputs each page so you should be able to work out which tikzpicture it is. try to make a small example with just that tikzpicture and see if it generates the problem.

Comment: google for tikz@signal@path errors suggests that you might have a mis matched `]`  see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338869/pdflatex-hangs-on-a-pending

Comment: Does Italian have shorthands? If so, add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. Probably not the issue here, but maybe useful. Consider using something like `geometry` rather than setting layout dimensions manually. `geometry` will make sure the backend paper size matches the layout automatically.

Comment: In that tikz picture the last two lines are malformed, but you should get an error at that point: `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?` rather than a stuck compilation

Comment: I did not get any error or any warning, I don't know why. I deleted the last two lines, and it worked. I will try again to insert the two labels for the vectors. Thanks

Comment: Either `\node at ...` or `\draw (1,1) node ...`. Note the lack of backslash in the second case.